# Touch attacks on D&D 5e

Tags: combat, dnd-5e, magic

Looking at this question,

[Does a touch spell require an attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47336/does-a-touch-spell-require-an-attack)

I assume that touch attacks no longer ignore AC provided by armor, or more exactly because of the new armor rules, make your AC 10+DEX (10 if your armor ignores DEX modifiers?) versus those attacks.

Is this correct? If not, how do touch attacks work?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is solved by reading the rulebook, and appears to be simply a request for us to explain rules explained in a rule book the asker simply has not yet obtained.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but can be useful because the old habits from 3.5, we use to think that the rule X was very logic and that it keeps that way on the new edition.  Sure someone is making touch attacks without AC in D&D 5e, I done it on one of my first session without thinking too much about it, the doubt came up later on the after play chat.

Comment: "Potentially useful for others" doesn't really justify a question that doesn't demonstrate good-faith effort at research or understanding before asking us to re-iterate (rather than explain a confusion about) something from a free-to-download pdf.

Comment: Ok, I voted myself for closing, go ahead and sorry for being off-topic

Comment: If, *after* you've read the rules, you're still confuzzled, we'll be happy to help out.

Comment: Seems pretty clear, but, as I'm waiting for the PHB and have a discussion over it at first sessions, I thought I could ask here.  All of you are right, the way the touch attacks work must be fully explained in BD&D rules, it has no sense to keep the rule for PHB.

Comment: To be more clear (and on my defense), when I asked, I was pretty sure of the rule (no special touch attacks), BUT some people still believes that is common sense that touch attacks (shocking grasp was my discussion about) MUST ignore armor because it offers no protection versus someone simply touching you, so I thought that it will be good that the community support my view of the rules.

Maybe I should had rewrite the question.

Comment: @CorvenDallas Rewrite it or do research. The question says: "Someone mentioned touch attacks. How do they work?" - which you can find out by reading the book. _If you do that and are still confused,_ tell us how, like BESW points out. If you have done that already and are still confused, edit your question to point out that you have done so and explain _in what way_ you're confused. (If you haven't done that, or it's clear once you do, you can leave it closed as is.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no longer such a thing as a 'touch attack'.

From the linked question: Touch only indicates the range, the target has to be within your natural reach (5' for a medium or small character).

If the spell says it requires an attack, that is a spell attack, not a 'touch' attack.
Spell attacks are d20 + proficiency bonus + spell attack modifier, resolved against AC in the standard way. Within the current rules, a creature has a single AC value which doesn't change depending on the type of attack.

You can look up the rules on spellcasting in general and spell attacks in particular in the Basic Rules available for free use [here](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/DnDBasicRules.pdf).